# How to get ID Parent from Child ID when i have className of the Parents JQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

First, I'm sorry , I don't speak english very well,

I want get ID of the p:dialog in Javascript by using id of its child p:inputText and the class="ui-dialog-title" of the client side of p:dialog.

```
<h:form id="formID" >

<p:dialog id="DialogID"  header="Title"  widgetVar="v_DialogID">

        <p:inputText   id="InputID"  value="#{bean.input}"  onblur="changeTitle(this.id)" />

</p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

Comment: Show the **generated** client side html. The server side xhtml is useless. Totally not PrimeFaces or even jsf related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is what you are asking. Correct me if I'm wrong.

`$("#InputID").parent().attr("id");` Will get you the id of an element's immediate parent.

`$("#InputID").parents()` Will get you all of the parents for an element.

`$("#InputID").parents(".class").each(function () { console.log($(this).attr("id")); });` Will get you the ids of every parent with a given class for an element.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but in your response, you use first() because p:dialog its the first parent of the input, but when i will have many parents of the input, what can i use intead of ?

Comment: In that case use the .parents() selector. You can say $("#InputID").parents(".ui-dialog-title").each(function () { console.log($(this).attr("id"));}); This will get you the ids of all of the parents of an element

Comment: If you are looking for a parent with a specific id, you can say .parents("#SpecificID"). And if you want to get all parents until a certain parent, use the .parentsUntil() method. These are all outlined in the jquery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/parents/    https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/

Comment: Thx u for all your responses, i will try this tomorow.